# Weakness of the test

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

By performing a hypothesis test on a sample from a normal population, you find that the hypothesis $\mu = 20$ cannot be rejected at $10\%$ risk. A colleague obtains the same conclusion by testing $\mu= 22$.

I think this is the weakness of the test: several hypotheses may not be rejected. Am I wrong?

Comment: If the mean of the sample is 21 and the standard error is 5, I should hope that nobody looking at the sample rejects 20 or 22 as a possibility. I would hope that a third scientist coming along somehow interested in the number 23 would also find that it is consistent with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifying a null hypothesis without expliciting an alternative does not make sense.

Then, to compare your test with your friend's one you can calculate the two $p_{value}$'s.

A test is measured by its $p_{value}$.

If the alternative is a simple hypothesis too, you can also calculate the power of both tests to compare them

Comment: So my answer does not make sense, right?

Comment: @Robert : your answer makes sense, in the sense that it is true that several hypothesis can be rejected but rejection is a decision "YES" or "NO". Actually you have to evaluate also at which level you reject an hypothesis. If you pvalue is 0.0006% or 9% in both cases you reject at 10% risk but the two situations are not exactly the same